# Prove that two polynomials of degree $m$ and $n$ intersect in at most $m$ points

Tags: calculus

> Let $m \leq n$ be two positive integers. Prove that two polynomials of degree $m$ and $n$ intersect in at most $m$ points.

This seemed simple enough: $f(x) = (x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_m)$ and $g(x)=(x-x_1)\cdots(x-x_n)$. When we set them equal we can simplify to get a polynomial with degree $n$ which has at most $n$ zeroes.

Does this proof work or do I need to be more rigorous?

Comment: What does it mean for polynomials to intersect? Do you mean that when viewing them as functions, their graphs intersect?

Comment: $x^2$ and $x$ intersect at 2 points. I think you mean to prove that they intersect in at most $n$ points.

Comment: Why should they necessarily have the same roots?

Comment: Are you sure you asked the right question? A line (degree 1) and a parabola (degree 2) can intersect in two points.

Comment: @HenningMakholm at most $n$ actually.

Comment: $f(x)-g(x)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$, that has at most $n$ roots. As @Dedalus said, your argument is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust at most $n$

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: at nost.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't assume that the two polynomials are monic or split into linear factors. They might not, unless the underlying field is algebraically closed.

Fortunately, you don't *need* that assumption. Just subtract the polynomials and note that the difference will have degree at most $n$.

... unless $m=n$ and the polynomials are *equal*, in which case they'll have lots and lots of points in common.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, they intersect at most $n$ times.

As for your reasoning, it is basically correct. If they intersect at more than $n$ points, then $f - g$ is an $n^{\text{th}}$ degree polynomial with more than $n$ roots which is impossible.

This reasoning breaks when $m = n$, can you see why?

Comment: So the question is wrong? It should say $m < n$?

Comment: @user19405892, Actually, the reasoning breaks when $m=n$ _and_ $f=g$.

Comment: Not necessarily. There should just be a caveat. Perhaps it should read, "Prove that two unequal polynomials of degree $m$ and $n$..."

Comment: @User8128 It is though. The question says $m$ instead of $n$ as well.

Comment: I'm just pointing out that the statement isn't true when $f = g$. That's all.